# PSQL filter by timestamp field by minutes

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have a table that has a column called begin_time which is of type timestamp in a postgres db.

```
         begin_time     
------------------------
 2014-06-02 10:00:00-04
 2016-04-07 16:45:00-04
```

How do I filter based on the minute values in this table? I want the times where minutes = 45.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `EXTRACT` combined with `WHERE`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM your-table
WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM begin_time) = '45'
```

For more information about the arguments which can be used with `EXTRACT` see the official [tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-extract/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXTRACT function like this:

SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) AS CURRENT_MINUTE FROM DUAL;

visit the site http://mycodesoftware.com/ for more details.